# Writing a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that recently had a domain name change, and I am trying to set the rules up to include ANYTHING that is after the ruleset to be redirected (sub domains currently work, but file exensions do not) The current ruleset I have in place is:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com [R=301,L]
```

If I go to www.example.com/subdomain/ or www.example.com/subdomain/another_directory/ it redirects to the appropriate site, but if I go to www.example.com/subdomain/file.ext or www.example.com/subdomain/another_directory/file.ext, the redirect does not work. I know I need to change the regex so that it works correctly, but i'm not sure what it needs to be changed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using captured group in target URL. Use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

[You don't need `mod_rewrite` for this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

A simpler, lighter approach would be

```
RedirectMatch ^/subdomain/ http://subdomain.example.com/
```

Comment: I tried using that method, except the problem is that most of what they are trying to access is no longer available, or no longer in the same file/tree structure. I wanted to just redirect them to the main page of the new website. So when they go to http://www.example.com/subdomain/Folder/File.ext it's trying to redirect to http://subdomain.example.com/File.ext which may not exist anymore, so I just want them to be redirected to http://subdomain.example.com/

Comment: OK. Your question implied that you *wanted* to redirect to the file - that's what @anubhava's answer is doing, too. The `RedirectMatch` for this case is even simpler; I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just noticed the wording of the original question, and was attemping to append to it. I apologize or the confusion and I thank both of you two for your prompt responses.